# Dataframe split before a specific string for all rows

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe (df) that contains 30 000 rows coming from a web scraping exercice

```
Name     NameID                                                            Age

John     www.link.com/www.link.com/https://www.link.com/ct/John             25
Samanta  www.link.com/www.link.com/https://www.link.com/ct/Samanta          24
Johnny   www.link.com/www.link.com/                                         22
Mary     www.link.com/www.link.com/https://www.link.com/ct/Mary             35
```

I want to clean the "NameID" row in a way where i only read "https://www.link.com/ct/ " part. So my output dataframe should look like this :

```
 Name     NameID                                  Age

John     https://www.link.com/ct/John             25
Samanta  https://www.link.com/ct/Samanta          24
Johnny                                            22
Mary     https://www.link.com/ct/Mary             35
```

My code so far:

```
df['NameID'] = df['NameID'].str.split("https://www.link.com/ct/")[1][1]
df['NameID'] =  "https://www.link.com/ct/" + df['NameID'].astype(str)
```

The output looks like this now:

```
Name     NameID                                  Age

John     https://www.link.com/ct/John             25
Samanta  https://www.link.com/ct/John             24
Johnny   https://www.link.com/ct/John             22
Mary     https://www.link.com/ct/John             35
```

Any help?

Comment: Sounds like you need a regular expression.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're close, you need `.str[1]`. Try changing your code to this:

```
df['NameID'] = df['NameID'].str.split("https://www.link.com/ct/").str[1]
df['NameID'] =  "https://www.link.com/ct/" + df['NameID'].astype(str)
```

---

```
df

      Name                           NameID  Age
0     John     https://www.link.com/ct/John   25
1  Samanta  https://www.link.com/ct/Samanta   24
2   Johnny      https://www.link.com/ct/nan   22
3     Mary     https://www.link.com/ct/Mary   35
```

You can tweak your code a bit to return back a `''`, as you specified in your desired outcome.

Answer (score 2):

```py
interested_part = "https://www.link.com/ct/"
df["NameID"] = df["NameID"].str.extract(fr"({interested_part}.*)$").fillna("")
```

the regex captures `interested_part + what_comes_after_till_the_end`. In case it can't match, it will return `NaN` (e.g. for Johnny) and we *fill* those cases with empty string:

```py
      Name                           NameID  Age
0     John     https://www.link.com/ct/John   25
1  Samanta  https://www.link.com/ct/Samanta   24
2   Johnny                                    22
3     Mary     https://www.link.com/ct/Mary   35
```

Answer (score 1):

The below code will help you. I added comments for better understanding.

```
#get the length of the required remove link
removeLinkLen = len('www.link.com/www.link.com/')

# function to get substring of the NameID after the last character of the removed link
def removeLink(x):
    return x[removeLinkLen:]

# apply function on NameID Column
df['NameID'] = df['NameID'].apply(removeLink)


    Name    NameID  Age
0   John    https://www.link.com/ct/John    25
1   Samanta https://www.link.com/ct/Samanta 24
2   Johnny                                  22
3   Mary    https://www.link.com/ct/Mary    35
```